# How does Miranda rights work in regards to sign-language?

Tags: fifth-amendment, miranda-warning

If a person were to be interviewed by police and he responded in sign-language. What he said turn out to be false. In court his lawyer argued what he said could not be used against him because he did not say anything. Miranda right say what you say can be used against you, how does sign-language fit in with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You can say things in sign language

It wouldn’t be much of a language if you couldn’t.

Further, you can say things in writing and with body language like nods and head shakes.

The Miranda Waring is to advise you that anything you say can be used against you, even if what you say is non-verbal.